# Duplicate Column 0

Tags: mysql, sql

```
INSERT INTO KATH_USERS_VISITS (USERID, PLACEID, UTCTIME,WEEKDAY,HOUR, DURATION, NEXT_ID ) 
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT 9 , 5, '0' , 0 , 0 , 458.44000000000005 , 40 ) AS tmp 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT 1 
                    FROM KATH_USERS_VISITS 
                    WHERE USERID=9 
                    and PLACEID=5 
                    and UTCTIME='0' 
                    and WEEKDAY=0 
                    and HOUR=0 
                    and DURATION=458.44000000000005 
                    and NEXT_ID=40 ) 
LIMIT 1;
```

When i try to run this query it gives an error that duplicate column 0, i want to check if a record not exists then insert the value.

Answer (score 0):

You should give the columns some names.

Something like

```
SELECT  *   
FROM    ( 
            SELECT  9 Col0, 
                    5 Col1, 
                    '0' Col2, 
                    0 Col3, 
                    0 Col4, 
                    458.44000000000005 Col5, 
                    40 Col6
        ) AS tmp
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/36524)